# Spring 3.0 ORM with JPA 2.0 ClassCastException

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm trying to use [JPA 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API#JPA_2.0) in Spring 3.0 ORM. The JPA vendor is [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) 3.5.0-Beta-3.

It works well with [JPQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language), but when I tried to use CriteriaQuery, an exception happens:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy50
>   cannot be cast to
>   javax.persistence.TypedQuery     at
>   $Proxy38.createQuery(Unknown Source)
>       at
>   com.absorbx.retailx.dao.impl.ShopDaoImpl.findByCrieria(ShopDaoImpl.java:30)
>       at
>   com.absorbx.retailx.dao.SimpleDaoTest.testFindByCriteria(SimpleDaoTest.java:39)
>       at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)

The [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) code:

```
@Repository
public class ShopDaoImpl implements
ShopDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    transient EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Shop findByCrieria() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Shop> c = cb.createQuery(Shop.class);
        Root<Shop> shop = c.from(Shop.class);
        c.select(shop).where(cb.equal(shop.get("name"), "petstore"));
        TypedQuery<Shop> q = entityManager.createQuery(c);
        return q.getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Spring:

`org/springframework/orm/jpa/SharedEntityManagerCreator.java`:

```
if (result instanceof Query) {
    Query query = (Query) result;
    ...
    result = Proxy.newProxyInstance(Query.class.getClassLoader(), 
        new Class[] {Query.class}, new DeferredQueryInvocationHandler(query, target));
    ...
}
```

It would be better to create an issue.

Comment: Good catch. Spring is checking to see if the query is an instance of `Query`, and generates the proxy of that type. Unfortunately, `TypedQuery` is a subtype of `Query`, and the generated proxy will still only implement `Query`. `TypedQuery` was introduced in JavaEE 6, so it's understandable why Spring doesn't handle it, although Spring 3 *is* supposed to handle JavaEE 6 properly. Definitely a bug.

Comment: Thanks, dude.
I created issuse:
http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6733
It's my first time to report bug:)